# Where is TFS 2010 Team Build Revision $(Rev:.r) Stored?

Tags: tfsbuild

TFS 2010 exposes a "Build Number Format" property, which contains $(BuildNumberDefinitionName) and $(Rev:.r) variables (among other things).  Two and a half parts to my question:

1. What are all the available variables that can be used here?
2. Where does the value for $(Rev:.r) come from (where is it stored)?

   a. Can it be reset or changed?

Comment: In answer to 2a, see my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24049746/2563198

Answer (score 20, accepted):

http://www.richardmaxwell.name/blog/2011/5/5/force-tfs-build-revision-to-a-specifc-value.html

Anytime you change your Build Number in a TFS build, the revision resets to 1, which is what it should do, most of the time.  But sometimes, you want to start at revision 100, maybe recreating a deleted build definition, or just wanting to maintain the old revision into a new branch.  It took me a lucky accident to discover how this is possible.  You must replace the dynamic revision with a hard coded one, build, and then change it back.    Out of frustration I eventually tried this:

Build Number Format: 1.0.0.100

This gave me the build I wanted, and then changed it back to this:

Build Number Format: 1.0.0$(Rev:.r)

This picked up my last value, starting future build at 1.0.0.101, instead of incrementing the last version that it had used, 1.0.0.2.  So I was able to skip builds 1 through 99 and start at revision 100 in my build number.

Comment: FYI This no longer works in TFS2015. I would assume it does not work on VSOnline as well.

Answer (score 2):

Open a build definition, go process tab, find "Build Number Format" section and click "..." button at end of it. Here you will see a "Macros>>" button that contains all available variables. As far as I know $(Rev:.r) tells that it's Nth time that this definition has been run in a specific date. It is store in TFS internal database.

Comment: Is there no supported way to see the current value and reset it?

Comment: To see current value, I check completed/queued builds of the build definition. But for resenting have now idea.

Comment: Completed/Queued builds could be deleted so I don't think that's an accurate way to know which build will be next.