# Can Visual Studio Project files override TFS generated build numbers?

Tags: tfs, build

I am using TFS 2012 and the OOTB default build template.  I have a build definition that uses the default Build Number Format of:

$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

For some reason, the *revision* number generated by TFS is really, really large.  For example the last build was PrintOps-Main_20140626.**124829**.

Only one of my other builds definitions produces builds with such a high revision number.  That other build is CI build of this same solution. This leads me to believe that there is something in a project file that is overriding the TFS build number with some custom logic.  But I don't know if that is even possible.  All other build definitions' revision numbers start out at 1 and increment the revision number by 1 if a build is ran multiple times a day.  These build definitions also increment by 1, but they start out at 1248xx.

As troubleshooting I have tried different process templates and modified the Build number format.  Everything works as expected except the $(Rev:.r) portion.  As soon as I introduce the revision portion back into the build format, I get a very large number.

Is my suspicion correct that it must be some sort of override in a project file?  If so, any suggestions on what to look for?  There are several (15+) projects in this solution so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: No this is not possible. Build numbers are stores per definition in the TFS databases. TFS picks the last build since the definition was named and will increment by one. If it was (once) manually set to a higher number, it will pick that and increment from there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5901367/736079

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I am sure you are correct, but that didn't seem to be what was happening in my case.  I tried setting the revision as shown in your linked answer (by hardcoding a 1 in the build number format), and that worked for the next build.  I though great, its reset to 1 now, so if I go back to the default build format i should get a revision number of 2, but alas, it was 124831.

Answer (score 0):

I retried the build on a different day and pulled out individual sections of the build number format ($BuildDefinitionName,$Date,$rev) to test each piece individually.  I don't know if it was because the new builds were occuring on a different day or if using just $(Rev:.r) with nothing else in the build number format reset things, but I finally got the build number to come out correctly.