# Build Number Format, four digit revision number

Tags: tfs, build

Is there a way of formatting the revision in a Build Number Format to always be three digits long starting from 1000?

I have `$(Rev:.r)` which adds `.1` and `.2` to concurrent builds.

I want this to be `.1001`

This is TFS 2013.

I have tried .1rrr and get the exception

> Exception Message: Unable to expand the macro $(Rev:.1rrr) specified
>   in build number format

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

`$(Rev:.1rrr)`

(Tested on VS Online)

The caveat here is that this won't rollover to `2000` if you are doing more than 999 builds in a day.

Comment: I tried .rrrr to get 0001 originally and it didn't work - but I will try this on Monday. If i could get 999 builds in a day I would be happy!!

Comment: I found this as well, but it works when adding the `1` as a prefix. I would say that's a bug in the way the format expression is interpreted.

Comment: Cool. I'll try it out

Comment: Afraid that doesn't work in TFS2013 - I appreciate I didn't specify the version number in the question, but will upvote based on it working elsewhere. I'll update the question. I get exception Exception Message: Unable to expand the macro $(Rev:.1rrr) specified in build number format

Comment: what about pulling the ".1" out of parentheses? .1$(Rev:rrr)

Answer (score 0):

This *might* work on TFS2013. It *does not* work on TFS2015.

Hard code your Build Number Format.

```
1.0.0.100
```

Perform a build. Change the Build Number Format back.

```
1.0.0$(Rev:.r)
```

The build might pick up from the hardcoded build number.

This appears to work for TFS2010 according to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5901367/1789). Worth a shot in TFS2013!