# TFS 2015 vNext force build number

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Back in TFS 2013 you could temporarily hardcode a build number and then switch back to auto increment to skip ahead with build numbers. Now with TFS 2015 vNext, it seems like I can no longer do this. I went to make a new build definition and wanted to carry on from the last build number from my XAML build but it wouldn't move up.

Any ideas or workarounds for this?

Comment: Can you show a detail example ?

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work in TFS2015 according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914801/where-is-tfs-2010-team-build-revision-rev-r-stored/5901367#5901367   - you can see an example of what I'm trying to do in my comment in your answer.

Comment: Well, it's actually impossible. Please see my update answer.

Comment: Well, it did work up until TFS2015.  I would like to be able to convert my builds from XAML to vNext without losing my build count...

Comment: How did you achieve? Did it work in XAML build of TFS2015?  You can customize the  build Template of XAML build, however it can't be achieved in VNext Build. In VNext, you can only add build steps. I think this may be the reason.

Comment: I haven't tried in XAML TFS2015 yet (and now am afraid to).  For XAML you could set it under Process -> Advanced -> Build number format.  With vNext it's under General -> Build number format.  Both seem to understand the $(Rev:.r) syntax, but in terms of whatever was happening behind the scenes with jumping ahead in revisions via hardcoding the build number seems to be gone.

Answer (score 0):

It's also supported. Please check this link for detail steps:[Generate custom build numbers in TFS Build vNext](http://blog.ehn.nu/2015/10/generate-custom-build-numbers-in-tfs-build-vnext/)

---

**update**

Unfortunately, it's impossible.`$(Rev:.rr)` Its start by one.

> **What is $(Rev:.rr)?**
>
> To ensure that every completed build has a unique name. When a build
>   is completed, if nothing else in the build number has changed, the Rev
>   integer value is incremented by one.
>
> Source:[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190719(v=vs.120).aspx#rev)

Comment: Say you have mybuild$(rev:.r) which would auto increment the builds. Say you were at build 2 and needed to skip to 5 for whatever reason. You used to be able to remove the Rev and stick in 5 to force build 5.  After the build was done you could switch back to rev.